# Transact to MultiSigWallet.addOwner errored: JsonRpcEngine - response has no error or result for request:

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am running the gnosis multisigwallet.sol in Remix IDE .It was deployed sucessfully but while calling the addOwner,remoceownerand changeRequirement functions its throwing below error in metamask.
code:
/// This code was taken from: https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

/// @title Multisignature wallet - Allows multiple parties to agree on transactions before execution.
/// @author Stefan George - <stefan.george@consensys.net>
contract MultiSigWallet {
uint constant public MAX_OWNER_COUNT = 50;

event Confirmation(address indexed sender, uint indexed transactionId);
event Revocation(address indexed sender, uint indexed transactionId);
event Submission(uint indexed transactionId);
event Execution(uint indexed transactionId);
event ExecutionFailure(uint indexed transactionId);
event Deposit(address indexed sender, uint value);
event OwnerAddition(address indexed owner);
event OwnerRemoval(address indexed owner);
event RequirementChange(uint required);

mapping (uint => Transaction) public transactions;
mapping (uint => mapping (address => bool)) public confirmations;
mapping (address => bool) public isOwner;
address[] public owners;
uint public required;
uint public transactionCount;

struct Transaction {
    address destination;
    uint value;
    bytes data;
    bool executed;
}

modifier onlyWallet() {
    if (msg.sender != address(this))
        revert();
    _;
}

modifier ownerDoesNotExist(address owner) {
    if (isOwner[owner])
        revert();
    _;
}

modifier ownerExists(address owner) {
    if (!isOwner[owner])
        revert();
    _;
}

modifier transactionExists(uint transactionId) {
    if (transactions[transactionId].destination == 0)
        revert();
    _;
}

modifier confirmed(uint transactionId, address owner) {
    if (!confirmations[transactionId][owner])
        revert();
    _;
}

modifier notConfirmed(uint transactionId, address owner) {
    if (confirmations[transactionId][owner])
        revert();
    _;
}

modifier notExecuted(uint transactionId) {
    if (transactions[transactionId].executed)
        revert();
    _;
}

modifier notNull(address _address) {
    if (_address == 0)
        revert();
    _;
}

modifier validRequirement(uint ownerCount, uint _required) {
    if (   ownerCount > MAX_OWNER_COUNT
        || _required > ownerCount
        || _required == 0
        || ownerCount == 0)
        revert();
    _;
}

/// @dev Fallback function allows to deposit ether.
function()
    payable
{
    if (msg.value > 0)
        Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

/*
 * Public functions
 */
/// @dev Contract constructor sets initial owners and required number of confirmations.
/// @param _owners List of initial owners.
/// @param _required Number of required confirmations.
function MultiSigWallet(address[] _owners, uint _required)
    public
    validRequirement(_owners.length, _required)
{
    for (uint i=0; i<_owners.length; i++) {
        if (isOwner[_owners[i]] || _owners[i] == 0)
            revert();
        isOwner[_owners[i]] = true;
    }
    owners = _owners;
    required = _required;
}

/// @dev Allows to add a new owner. Transaction has to be sent by wallet.
/// @param owner Address of new owner.
function addOwner(address owner)
    public
    onlyWallet
    ownerDoesNotExist(owner)
    notNull(owner)
    validRequirement(owners.length + 1, required)
{
    isOwner[owner] = true;
    owners.push(owner);
    OwnerAddition(owner);
}

/// @dev Allows to remove an owner. Transaction has to be sent by wallet.
/// @param owner Address of owner.
function removeOwner(address owner)
    public
    onlyWallet
    ownerExists(owner)
{
    isOwner[owner] = false;
    for (uint i=0; i<owners.length - 1; i++)
        if (owners[i] == owner) {
            owners[i] = owners[owners.length - 1];
            break;
        }
    owners.length -= 1;
    if (required > owners.length)
        changeRequirement(owners.length);
    OwnerRemoval(owner);
}

/// @dev Allows to replace an owner with a new owner. Transaction has to be sent by wallet.
/// @param owner Address of owner to be replaced.
/// @param newOwner Address of new owner.
function replaceOwner(address owner, address newOwner)
    public
    onlyWallet
    ownerExists(owner)
    ownerDoesNotExist(newOwner)
{
    for (uint i=0; i<owners.length; i++)
        if (owners[i] == owner) {
            owners[i] = newOwner;
            break;
        }
    isOwner[owner] = false;
    isOwner[newOwner] = true;
    OwnerRemoval(owner);
    OwnerAddition(newOwner);
}

/// @dev Allows to change the number of required confirmations. Transaction has to be sent by wallet.
/// @param _required Number of required confirmations.
function changeRequirement(uint _required)
    public
    onlyWallet
    validRequirement(owners.length, _required)
{
    required = _required;
    RequirementChange(_required);
}

/// @dev Allows an owner to submit and confirm a transaction.
/// @param destination Transaction target address.
/// @param value Transaction ether value.
/// @param data Transaction data payload.
/// @return Returns transaction ID.
function submitTransaction(address destination, uint value, bytes data)
    public
    returns (uint transactionId)
{
    transactionId = addTransaction(destination, value, data);
    confirmTransaction(transactionId);
}

/// @dev Allows an owner to confirm a transaction.
/// @param transactionId Transaction ID.
function confirmTransaction(uint transactionId)
    public
    ownerExists(msg.sender)
    transactionExists(transactionId)
    notConfirmed(transactionId, msg.sender)
{
    confirmations[transactionId][msg.sender] = true;
    Confirmation(msg.sender, transactionId);
    //executeTransaction(transactionId);
}

/// @dev Allows an owner to revoke a confirmation for a transaction.
/// @param transactionId Transaction ID.
function revokeConfirmation(uint transactionId)
    public
    ownerExists(msg.sender)
    confirmed(transactionId, msg.sender)
    notExecuted(transactionId)
{
    confirmations[transactionId][msg.sender] = false;
    Revocation(msg.sender, transactionId);
}

/// @dev Allows anyone to execute a confirmed transaction.
/// @param transactionId Transaction ID.
// function executeTransaction(uint transactionId)
//     public
//     ownerExists(msg.sender)
//     confirmed(transactionId, msg.sender)
//     notExecuted(transactionId)
// {
//     if (isConfirmed(transactionId)) {
//         Transaction storage txn = transactions[transactionId];
//         txn.executed = true;
//         if (txn.destination.call.value(txn.value)(txn.data))
//             Execution(transactionId);
//         else {
//             ExecutionFailure(transactionId);
//             txn.executed = false;
//         }
//     }
// }

/// @dev Returns the confirmation status of a transaction.
/// @param transactionId Transaction ID.
/// @return Confirmation status.
function isConfirmed(uint transactionId)
    public
    constant
    returns (bool)
{
    uint count = 0;
    for (uint i=0; i<owners.length; i++) {
        if (confirmations[transactionId][owners[i]])
            count += 1;
        if (count == required)
            return true;
    }
}

/*
 * Internal functions
 */
/// @dev Adds a new transaction to the transaction mapping, if transaction does not exist yet.
/// @param destination Transaction target address.
/// @param value Transaction ether value.
/// @param data Transaction data payload.
/// @return Returns transaction ID.
function addTransaction(address destination, uint value, bytes data)
    internal
    notNull(destination)
    returns (uint transactionId)
{
    transactionId = transactionCount;
    transactions[transactionId] = Transaction({
        destination: destination,
        value: value,
        data: data,
        executed: false
    });
    transactionCount += 1;
    Submission(transactionId);
}

/*
 * Web3 call functions
 */
/// @dev Returns number of confirmations of a transaction.
/// @param transactionId Transaction ID.
/// @return Number of confirmations.
function getConfirmationCount(uint transactionId)
    public
    constant
    returns (uint count)
{
    for (uint i=0; i<owners.length; i++)
        if (confirmations[transactionId][owners[i]])
            count += 1;
}

/// @dev Returns total number of transactions after filers are applied.
/// @param pending Include pending transactions.
/// @param executed Include executed transactions.
/// @return Total number of transactions after filters are applied.
function getTransactionCount(bool pending, bool executed)
    public
    constant
    returns (uint count)
{
    for (uint i=0; i<transactionCount; i++)
        if (   pending && !transactions[i].executed
            || executed && transactions[i].executed)
            count += 1;
}

/// @dev Returns list of owners.
/// @return List of owner addresses.
function getOwners()
    public
    constant
    returns (address[])
{
    return owners;
}

/// @dev Returns array with owner addresses, which confirmed transaction.
/// @param transactionId Transaction ID.
/// @return Returns array of owner addresses.
function getConfirmations(uint transactionId)
    public
    constant
    returns (address[] _confirmations)
{
    address[] memory confirmationsTemp = new address[](owners.length);
    uint count = 0;
    uint i;
    for (i=0; i<owners.length; i++)
        if (confirmations[transactionId][owners[i]]) {
            confirmationsTemp[count] = owners[i];
            count += 1;
        }
    _confirmations = new address[](count);
    for (i=0; i<count; i++)
        _confirmations[i] = confirmationsTemp[i];
}

/// @dev Returns list of transaction IDs in defined range.
/// @param from Index start position of transaction array.
/// @param to Index end position of transaction array.
/// @param pending Include pending transactions.
/// @param executed Include executed transactions.
/// @return Returns array of transaction IDs.
function getTransactionIds(uint from, uint to, bool pending, bool executed)
    public
    constant
    returns (uint[] _transactionIds)
{
    uint[] memory transactionIdsTemp = new uint[](transactionCount);
    uint count = 0;
    uint i;
    for (i=0; i<transactionCount; i++)
        if (   pending && !transactions[i].executed
            || executed && transactions[i].executed)
        {
            transactionIdsTemp[count] = i;
            count += 1;
        }
    _transactionIds = new uint[](to - from);
    for (i=from; i<to; i++)
        _transactionIds[i - from] = transactionIdsTemp[i];
}
```

}

```
error:transact to MultiSigWallet.addOwner errored: JsonRpcEngine - response has no error or result for request:
```

and find the error screenshot also.Can any tell me how to resolve this issue.--[image]Thanks

Comment: Please post the code that gives you this error and the error message so that it can be read. In text and not a screenshot.

Comment: Hi nikos, I added the code what I tried

Comment: Thanks for posting the code but next time please make sure the indentation is correct, it is really hard to read it like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the modifiers of these functions you will notice they both have the modifier `onlyWallet`. This means that only the wallet can call these functions.
If I remove these modifiers the transactions do not revert.

I am not sure how this contract was meant to be used and why it has public functions that cannot be called by anyone.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Is not possible Without removing onlywallet modifier to call those functions?

Comment: Well, I don't see another way. This modifier requires that the sender of the transaction is the contract itself. If you want to restrict access you can add another modifier (e.g. onlyOwner).